# Conditional GROUP BY and additional columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
Insert into x (...)
select a,b,c from prq where p_a is null group by a,b,c
```

Now, my requirement is that, if `p_a is null` then i have to group by a,b,c and select only a,b,c column.

But if `p_a is not null` then, i have to group by two new column x,y and also select these two columns.
These x,y columns are NULLABLE in table x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table X must have at least five columns whose names, we can presume, are `a`, `b`, `c`, `x`, `y`.

If you are doing a single INSERT, then you'll need to insert into all five columns.  If you are doing multiple INSERT operations, you can insert into 3 and then 5 (or vice versa) columns.  You may have to do some juggling with the NULL values in the select-list of the first alternative.  I'm assuming that the columns `x` and `y` are INTEGER for definiteness - choose the appropriate type.

#### 1st Alternative

```
INSERT INTO x(a, b, c, x, y)
    SELECT a, b, c, MAX(CAST(NULL AS INTEGER)) AS x, MAX(CAST(NULL AS INTEGER)) AS y
      FROM pqr
     WHERE p_a IS NULL
     GROUP BY a, b, c
    UNION
    SELECT MAX(a) AS a, MAX(b) AS b, MAX(c) AS c, x, y
      FROM pqr
     WHERE p_a IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY x, y;
```

You could replace the `GROUP BY a, b, c` clause with a DISTINCT in front of `a` in the select-list of the first part of the UNION.  In most SQL DBMS, you must list all the non-aggregate columns from the select-list in the GROUP BY clause.  Using the MAX means that you have aggregates for `x` and `y` in the first half of the UNION and for `a`, `b` and `c` in the second half of the UNION.

#### 2nd Alternative

```
INSERT INTO x(a, b, c)
    SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c
      FROM pqr
     WHERE p_a IS NULL;
INSERT INTO x(a, b, c, x, y)
    SELECT MAX(a) AS a, MAX(b) AS b, MAX(c) AS c, x, y
      FROM pqr
     WHERE p_a IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY x, y;
```

As discussed before, you need aggregates on the columns not in the GROUP BY list.

#### 3rd Alternative

If you meant that you must group by `x` and `y` as well as `a`, `b` and `c`, then the second half of the UNION (or the second SELECT) simplifies to:

```
    SELECT a, b, c, x, y
      FROM pqr
     WHERE p_a IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY a, b, c, x, y;
```

Or you can use DISTINCT again:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, x, y
      FROM pqr
     WHERE p_a IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: select a,b,c,case when p_a is null then .... from pqr group by a,b,c,case...is this works ?

Comment: If I understand what you're suggesting correctly, I don't think so because you need two separate sets of grouping - though there is some ambiguity in your specification and it is possible that a single grouping is all you need, and then with two appropriate CASE expressions in the select-list, you might be able to make it all work after all.  I'm not sure you'd need the CASE in the GROUP BY clause, but I'd need to see your proposal in more detail to be sure.

Comment: jonathan: case in group by works for me ,but i am not sure of group by a,b,c, case when ...else null.....Is this null will affect my result?

Comment: Since I can't see or envisage all your SQL, I don't know.  It may work; it may not.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @p_a datatype

select @p_a= P_a from prq

if(@p_a is null)

select a,b,c from prq group by a,b,c

else

select a,b,c from prq group by x,y
```

Comment: but i want to use this with insert statement

Comment: its not small query its 700 lines query